# ImportError: No module named mysql.connector

Tags: python, mysql-connector

I am using windows, I recently installed mysql connector, now when I am trying to establish connection with MySql I am getting the following error:
"ImportError: No module named mysql.connector"

I am attaching the screenshot of the error.

Code which I am using to establish a connection is :
import mysql.connector
mydb=mysql.connector.connect([enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y9o9X.jpg)host='localhost',user='root',password='kicker12345@pk')
print(mydb.connection_id)

Comment: Then you probably did not install mysql.connector properly or it is installed in a different virtual environment